# Knockout add/bind data to object inside foreach

Tags: knockout.js, typeahead.js

**Hello overflowers!**

I having issues binding data to an object inside a foreach loop. Right now I'm using typeahead to get autocomplete functionality. When i do this i can save the Id of a specific object in a variable. I want to add this Id to the product object.

The issues is attaching the specific ID to the specific product.

The user can add or remove products / input fields with autocomplete functionality on demand.

```
 function Product() {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(null);
    self.name = ko.observable(); };

    var dataWithID = 12345; //this id comes from another function, will change.
    //TODO: Attach the specific id to the product object.

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selected = ko.observable();
    self.products = ko.observableArray([new Product()]);
    self.add = function () {
        self.products.push(new Product());
    } };


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cH2NX/1/

/J

Comment: Do  you want to add this ID to every product that is added through your self.add function or do you want to retrieve somehow id for each product that user adds?

Comment: I wanta to add the specific ID to the product that im typing in. I use typeahead to gain autocomple functionality, which returns the name and the id of the product. So every product will have a unique id.

Comment: Is there any sort of a callback javascript function when you get the product selected with the typeahead? Can you post it as well?

Comment: I can do what ever i want with the ID from typeahead. Its a knockout binding handler that takes care of the job.

Comment: can you show us the code where you get the ID from the typeahead?

Answer (score 1):

Just push it into product like so

```
function Product(id) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(); 
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selected = ko.observable();
    self.products = ko.observableArray([new Product()]);
    self.add = function () {
        self.products.push(new Product(dataWithID)); // <-- pass in here
    } 
};
```

Comment: then i have the issue of the first object will not have a id. It will also be a must to add a new product, even if you are done, to add the latest product. I want to have a new product ready and attach the id to the already added product. Do u understand the issue im addressing?

Comment: I dont have the id when the model is being instantiated. The self.products list have one object with a ID that i dont know...

Comment: You need to give us where the id is coming from and how you are handling it for us to be able to remotely try to help you.